# Implementation time of Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR)

Tags: pic, fpga, vhdl, dsp

From implementation point of view, how much time will pseudorandom number generation by Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) take when implemented on, for example, Digital Signal Processor? Seed is supposed to be 4 bit long. How can the implementation time be calculated before actually implementing LFSR?

Any help/hint is appreciated!

Comment: do a software emulation of it and check if the output satisfies demand.

Comment: Are you asking how long it would take to write the LFSR code?

Comment: @scary_jeff, no, question says "take when implemented on", past tense. OP's after execution time. Generously allowing 3 instructions for the read shift and final store, allowing for up to a 32-bit LFSR, allowing 5 instructions per tap and allowing 5 taps means it's less than 30 instructions. Probably a lot less but no more 30 than instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of the LSFR algorithm.

There's the hardware implementation, which computes parity = (bitcount(state&mask))&1, and shifts the parity bit into the end of the word. This maps well onto hardware shift registers, but is not software efficient. It's the computation of the parity that will tend not have a single cycle bitcount() operation available.

Then there's the software implementation, which works on a whole word at a time. Pseudocode for this is

```
if (state&1 == 1)
     state = state XOR mask;
state = state >> 1;
```

All state bits that correspond to the mask get conditionally XOR'd at the same time, when the LSB is 1, and left unaltered when it's 0. This only works easily for word lengths up to the native word length of the processor, but extension to multi-word operation is trivial.

The mask for the software type is the same as for the hardware type, except for being bit reversed, that is the MSB of one is the LSB of the other.

The execution time for a single bit changes depending on whether a 0 or 1 is present in the LSB, this may or may not be acceptable depending on your precise requirements. If a deterministic time is required, then you'll need an else statement padded with one or more NOPs according to your particular processor. As the total number of 0 and 1 bits is deterministic, you can calculate the run time for a whole 2^m-1 bits, and so the average time for one bit.

If you're trying to get the operations count down, maybe even thinking in assembler, then be aware that in many processors, a right shift operation drops the LSB into one of the flag bits, often the carry, to be available for multi-word shifts. This bit is often testable directly, so avoiding the need to mask off the LSB as a separate operation.

Comment: Some kinds of hardware may support the "software" version more easily than the hardware one.  For example, in a typical PLD or CPLD, the "software" version of an 16-bit LFSR with a polynomial configured using 16 inputs from somewhere would require 16 macrocells with three product terms each.  By contrast, the "hardware" version would likely need to use 15 macrocells with one product term each, and about six with over a dozen product terms each (reducing the number of extra macrocells would massively increase the number of product terms required; doing the job with 16 macrocells total...

Comment: ...would require that one of them have literally millions of product terms, since the number of product terms required for an expression of the form (x0 and y0) xor (x1 and y1) xor (x2 and y2) xor (x3 and y3) etc. will roughly triple with each element therein.

Answer (score 0):

A software implementation of a LFSR looks something like:

```
unsigned int LFSR(unsigned int* state, unsigned int mask){
    int resbit = state & 1;
    unsigned int parity = bitcount(*state & mask) & 1;
    *state = (*state >> 1) | parity << 31;
    return resbit;
}
```